# VS Code not running as root MacOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, macos-sierra

I was trying to edit some system files and I entered `sudo code <some-file>` and VS code would start, but it would not start as root.  I used t see some warnings that it was not recommended (for obvious reasons) but now it just seems to not run as root.

Was there some change or some setting I need to enable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by completely deleting the preferences in `~Library/preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.helper.plist` and `~Library/preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.plist`

This allowed me to run again as root once I restarted the application, I am not sure how or why I got into this state though.